# Keeping Fragment count to one

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

When I press a button, my app creates a fragment. I'd like to make sure that only one of this fragment is created, e.g. disable the button if the fragment already exists.

How do I check that it creates only one fragment? Is it possible to get a Fragment count or is there some option that limits it to creating only one?

Comment: Preferably without using one, would be nice to know if there's a built in option for it.

Comment: Have You tried FragmentManager.findFragmentById(int id) or findFragmentByTag(String tag) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the methods that sandrstar mentioned. When attaching a fragment u can first check to see if its already attached.

For example if you are adding the fragment dynamically you can stop the fragment from being re-added by doing the following:

```
MyFragment myFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragmentTag")
if(myFragment == null)
{
   myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
   FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.add(R.layout.mylayout,myFragment,"MyFragmentTag");
   ft.commit();
}
```